# What does "variable : function(){}" means?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a Node.JS example code I found a code block as follows.

```
var messageReceivedCallBack = {
    onMessageReceived: function (message) {
        console.log('Message received ' + message);
    }
};
```

What does this code means? Specifically I can't understand the part with the colon (' : ')

Comment: property names and values are  separated by `:` in a javascript object

Comment: in messageReceivedCallBack  object 'onMessageReceived' is a method/function name in it.

Comment: on a whole other thing, just a recommendation, use `console.log('Message received:`, message); instead. That makes it work when having a object/objects of any kind. The + works fine with strings and int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an object literal. That's not a variable, it's a property name:

```
var foo = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2
};
```

Is the same as:

```
var foo = {};
foo.a = 1;
foo.b = 2;
```

Similarly:

```
var foo = {
    a: function () {}
};
```

Is the same as:

```
var foo = {};
foo.a = function () {};
```

Therefore the following:

```
var messageReceivedCallBack = {
    onMessageReceived: function (message) {
        console.log('Message received ' + message);
    }
};
```

Is just doing this:

```
var messageReceivedCallBack = {};

messageReceivedCallBack.onMessageReceived = function (message) {
    console.log('Message received ' + message);
};
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you use my code instead of examples. It take more time to understand with these examples.

Comment: The examples were chosen to be as minimal as possible to make the core concept as easy to "see" as possible. I'll add your code as another example but I don't think it would be as easy to understand what's going on as the minimal examples.

Comment: Ok now it's easy for me.

Comment: @LasithaYapa Remember, Stack Overflow is not just here for you, but for others as well. The `foo`-style examples are a lot easier for all those other folks to translate to *their* own specific situation, making this answer (though perhaps slightly harder to understand for you) easier to understand for many others.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can read: [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, more ways to create objects/class.

1. construction function based class `(function ObjConstructor() {this.name="abc";})`
2. Object literals (`var myObj = { "key" : "value" }` (value can be function or number, string..,)

Here the **:** is separation of key value pair.
If you look into the JSON, you can understand easily. [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)